# Как создать приложение для android allways on display?

Tags: android

Как создать приложение для android allways on display что б оно выводило данные всегда на дисплей?

Comment: Ну... Может тут что-то полезное будет: https://github.com/rosenpin/AlwaysOnDisplayAmoled